# Why ionic APK for android is generating under the build/outputs/apki/debug/ folder and its not opening in device?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am building a android APK normally it will generate inside output/apk/ folder but now its generating inside output/apk/debug folder, So my problem is when I install this generated APK in device it's not opening why ?

My ionic info :

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

  Cordova CLI : 8.0.0

local packages:

  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
  Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

  Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
  Node              : v8.11.0
  npm               : 5.6.0
  OS                : Windows 7
```

Comment: Debug apks are generated in output/apk/debug folder and release apks are generated in output/apk/release folder, the fact that apk is not opening is not related to that, can you share logcat output when you open the app?

Comment: Does the app open if you run `cordova run android --device` while a device is connected?